# Postgres Group By Date with hours offset

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to use a different start and end time of the day when using the group by clause on the postgres
The requirement arose due to the business requirement where shops have different shop open and close hours so to calculate the sales for a day a shop will be open from morning 10 am to the next morning 3 am. In such a scenario the group by clause should consider 4 am to 3.59:59 am the next day as a single day instead of 00 to 23:59:59.

There is an existing feature AT TIMEZONE by postgres, but is it possible to do the group by clause without using AT TIMEZONE as it is not the intended use case?

Comment: Additionally, also the question is very low quality, as you're lacking debugging details to be added to answer the question properly, like sample input data and expected output.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1):

To have the day start at 4 a.m. rather than midnight, then subtract 4 hours from the time :

Simple data :

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  id int,
  sale_timestamp timestamp
);

insert into sales values
(1, '2023-01-01 04:00:15'), -- 2023-01-01
(2, '2023-01-01 04:00:15'), -- 2023-01-01
(3, '2023-01-02 02:00:00'), -- 2023-01-01 (since it is before 4am)
(4, '2023-01-02 04:15:15'), -- 2023-01-02
(5, '2023-01-02 04:15:15'); -- 2023-01-02

select (sale_timestamp - interval '1 hour' * 4)::date as sale_day, count(1)
from sales
group by sale_day
```

Result :

| sale_day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 3 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/clPSLhAu)